# Github module project deployment based on the event

Tags: git, jenkins, github, deployment

I have a GitHub repo which has many individual maven projects. I have a private Jenkins which polls this GitHub repo at every 2 hours for tracking the Commits and PullRequest events happened to GitHub repo. The Jenkins job is triggering fine whenever it finds any new Commits and PullRequest events.

My GitHub Project Hierarchy is shown below:

```
└─ ProjectRootDir  
             │                                
             ├─ ProjectModuleA
             │     ├─ project1
             │     ├─ project2
             │     ├─ project3
             │     ├─ project4
             │     ├─ project5
             │     └─ project6
             │
             ├─ ProjectModuleB
             │     ├─ project7
             │     ├─ project8
             │     └─ project9
             │
             ├─ ProjectModuleC
             │     ├─ project10
             │     └─ project11
             │
             ├─ ProjectModuleD
             │     ├─ project12
             │     ├─ project13
             │     ├─ project14
             │     ├─ project15
             │     ├─ project16
             │     └─ project17
             │
             └─ pom.xml
```

### Problem Statement:

Lets say someone commits some files to **project3** of **ProjectModuleA**. When the jenkins polling time comes, job will be triggered successfully since there is an event detected in GitHub. But now the issue is that I want to deploy only the **project3** to the server.

I have gone through the GitHub API where I saw many API's for getting the events (pull, commit, push etc).

```
https://api.github.com/repos/my-github-repo/events
```

But how do I know to which project it got committed so that I can do the selective deploy of that particular project (i.e **project3**)

Comment: If your schema is exhaustive, 17 jenkins jobs don't seem to be too much of a hassle, do they? Not the more elegant solution ever, but it would do the job(s).

Comment: @RomainVALERI Thanks for replying. I did'nt get that actually....can you please explain it a little more in detail

Comment: I mean that you could duplicate your jenkins job and point each copy to each subfolder to poll it specifically and deploy only its perimeter. Just a thought, maybe not ideal for other reasons in your very own context.

Comment: @RomainVALERI but what if happens if it commits to some branches...

Comment: look into multiBranchPipeline Job in jenkins

Comment: @rohitthomas I tried with that....but how that helps

Comment: So in multiBranchPipeline you can configure it for the entire repo where each project will have its respective JenkinsFile and in that file you will have the build and deploy so when a commit is done to a branch/project then Jenkins will trigger that projects jenkinsFile

Comment: @rohitthomas The thing is I dont have Jenkinsfile in none of the project.....I am using a custom Jenkinsfile for jenkins deployment for all the projects

Comment: now thats a headache ... try adding this to JenkinsFile JOB_NAME...should give you the job which is  building or you can try the other options available here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project

Comment: or what you can do is look into jenkins API and find out which project is building currently